# Using <TITLE> tag to load multiple different text string

Tags: javascript, html, tags, title

I've seen some sites (i.e., http://www.legworkstudio.com/) that have  tags that change at intervals and I assume it's done through Javascript, but I have not seen any kind of documentation on such an action.

I don't believe document.title will work for this, but maybe I have misunderstood how to use it properly.

Anybody seen something like this or how best to do this?

---

Basically in the HTML it would look like this every few seconds:

```
<title>Title 1</title>
```

then after a few seconds

```
<title>Title 2</title>
```

then after a few seconds more

```
<title>Title 3</title>
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ document.title = "Title " + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) }, 1000);`

Comment: Your question/accepted answer ratio is too low (zero, actually). You should start accepting answers to your questions if you want people help you in te future. People spend time helping you for a reason, so be grateful, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `document.title` would work just fine. Try this:

```
var titles = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"];
var currentTitle = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    document.title = titles[currentTitle];
    if (currentTitle < titles.length - 1) {
        currentTitle++;
    } else {
        currentTitle = 0;
    }
}, 3000);
```

If you add this script to your page, it should change the title of the page to the next element of the `titles` array every three seconds, looping back to the start of the array indefinitely.

To change the amount of time between changes, just change `3000` to the number of milliseconds you would like between changes.

To stop the cycle at any point, you can make use of `clearInterval()`.

Will this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the window setInterval method, then use a selector to modifify your title element content

From W3school docs:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods and properties in the `document` apart from `write`. In this case you can access and modify the title by using the `title` property.

With this and a timeout/interval you loop titles doing something like this:

```
var titles = ["Title 1", "My second title", "yay! third title shown!"];
setInterval(function() {
    document.title = titles.shift(); // Get the first element in the array and remove it.
    titles.push(document.title); // Push the element to the end of the array
}, 5000); // Milliseconds to loop
```

I like codegolf a bit, so you can do something like this :P:

```
setInterval(function() {
    titles.push(document.title = titles.shift()); // Get the first element in the array, remove it, assign it to title and push it back to the end of the array.
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I like this solution of push/shift instead of looping the array, pretty cool! A nifty bit of codegolf :D

Comment: @steveg Haha, thanx xD